# PowerMockito.whenNew not mocked if the subclass doesn't have any constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, powermockito

I have a inner private class called MyXStream which extends `com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream`.

OuterClass.java

```java
public class OuterClass {
  private class MyXStream extends XStream {
    @Override
    protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
      // implementation details
    }
  }

  public void myMethod() {
    XStream myXStream = new MyXStream();
  }
}
```

The test case I use

OuterClassTest.java

```java
Class myXStreamClass = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(OuterClass.class, "MyXStream");
XStream xStream = (XStream) PowerMockito.mock(myXStreamClass);
PowerMockito.whenNew(myXStreamClass).withNoArguments().thenReturn(xStream);
```

And it doesn't work. `myXStream` is null and cause the NullPointerException. Then I tried to add a constructor to MyXStream to see what happened like this:

```java
public class OuterClass {
  private class MyXStream extends XStream {
    public MyXStream() {
      // some debug statements
    }

    @Override
    protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
      // implementation details
    }
  }
}
```

And the test case worked.

I can also just replace `withNoArguments()` with `withAnyArguments()`, this also worked. Like this:

OuterClassTest.java

```java
Class myXStreamClass = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(OuterClass.class, "MyXStream");
XStream xStream = (XStream) PowerMockito.mock(myXStreamClass);
PowerMockito.whenNew(myXStreamClass).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(xStream);
```

I just wondering why can't I just use `withNoArguments()` if I didn't specify any constructor? Shouldn't the Java compiler create an empty one for me? What's the difference between them?

---

Update:

A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

OuterClass.java

```java
package test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper;

public class OuterClass {
    private class MyXStream extends XStream {
        @Override
        protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        XStream myXStream = new MyXStream();
        myXStream.fromXML("xml");
    }
}
```

OuterClassTest.java

```java
package test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({
        OuterClass.class
})
public class OuterClassTest {
    private OuterClass outerClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        outerClass = PowerMockito.spy(new OuterClass());
    }

    @Test
    public void myMethod() throws Exception {
        Class myXStreamClass = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(OuterClass.class, "MyXStream");
        XStream xStream = (XStream) PowerMockito.mock(myXStreamClass);

        // withAnyArguments() worked
        // PowerMockito.whenNew(myXStreamClass).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(xStream);

        // withNoArguments() will cause java.lang.NullPointerException
        PowerMockito.whenNew(myXStreamClass).withNoArguments().thenReturn(xStream);

        outerClass.myMethod();

        Mockito.verify(xStream, Mockito.times(1)).fromXML("xml");
    }

}
```

I realize that calling `new` directly in code is not suitable for testing, but I found that PowerMockito can mock new instance and having some strange behavior and don't know why.

- **Why withNoArguments() not working even my `new` statement doesn't pass any argument to it?**
- **Why adding an empty constructor to MyXStream solve this problem?**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: A) are you really following **all** required steps (see https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor )? Most often people forget about RunWith for PrepareForTest --- therefore I am asking for a [mcve] - you are not showing us the code to understand what is going on. and the usual B) mocking `new` is possible, but most often just a band aid on a *symptom*. Your real problem is that you wrote hard to test code. Don't  `new` in your code - use a DI framework instead, or at least pass in a factory that you can control in unit tests.

Comment: @GhostCat I would say the real problem here is the idea to *mock* the `XStream` dependency in the first place (as almost always the case, mocking is just the wrong choice), not that it gets "newed" (which is probably perfectly fine here).